# 2nd degree equation for two simultaneous lines

Tags: geometry, determinant, coordinate-systems, plane-geometry

We know that $$a{x^2}+2hxy+b{y^2}+2gx+2fy+c=0$$ is the 2nd degree equation for two simultaneous lines $y={m_k}x+{c_k};\, k=1,2$. But it needs to satisfy the following condition:
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a&h&g\\
h&b&f\\
g&f&c\\
\end{vmatrix}
=0$$
Why so?

P.S.: I know that the said 2nd degree equation may also be the equation of other curves (circle, ellipse or parabola). What I'm interested in is how does that determinant equation restrict it to lines.

Comment: I think that the intersection point $(p,q)$ leads to a zero eigenvector $(p,q,1)$, but I can't put together the calculation

Comment: @Vector You forgot about your problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see
$$ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0~~~(1)$$
as a quadratic of $x$ and treat $y$ as constant, then
$$ax^2+X(2hy+2g)+by^2+2fy+c=0$$ $$ \implies x=\frac{-(hy+g)\pm \sqrt{(hy+g)^2-a(by^2+2fy+c)}}{a}~~~(2)$$
(2) will represent two lines if the quardratic of $y$ inside the radical
$$h^2y^2+g^2+2hgy-aby^2-2afy-ac= (h^2-ab)y^2+y(2hg-2af)+(g^2-ac)=$$ is a perfect square. This requires $B^2=4AC$, then
$$4(hg-af)^2=4(h^2-ab)(g^2-ac)= 2fgh+abc-af^2-bg^2-ch^2=0~~~(3)$$
The RHS of (3) can be checked to be the expansion of the determinant mentioned by OP.

Comment: Well... I didn't actually forgot about it... I saw your answer and ya... I got it... it all looks so obvious now. The discriminant had to be perfect square and thus the discriminant had to be zero. Thx for the elegant solution.